# Defining a key in a property map using @Bean

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

Given the following piece of XML configuration:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
   <property name="environment">
      <map>
         <entry>
            <key><util:constant id="respectTTL" 
static-field="com....SOLACE_JMS_RESPECT_TIME_TO_LIVE"/>
             </key>
             <ref bean="booleanFalse"/>
         </entry>
      </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```

how would this part be defined in Java using **@Bean**:

```
<key><util:constant id="respectTTL" 
    static-field="com....SOLACE_JMS_RESPECT_TIME_TO_LIVE"/>
</key>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how the piece of XML can be transformed to Java config from XML?

Comment: yes - specifically, how would both the ID and the STATIC-FIELD be expressed in java as part of the key

Comment: What do you need the `ID` for?

Comment: it is part of XML config - perhaps am think now it is just not needed

Comment: The ID part isn't needed for that part of code to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's really isn't clear why you are afraid to do some Java code on the matter:

```
@Bean
public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();

    Properties environment = new Properties();
    environment.setProperty(com....SOLACE_JMS_RESPECT_TIME_TO_LIVE, "false");
    jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(environment);

    return jndiTemplate;
}
```

Since your constant is java code and, of course, `@Bean` is for java code you can simply use any java code from Spring Java Config.

We need `<util:constant>` just for XML definition, because we can't simply use any java code from XML.

BTW there is no reason to overhead Application Context with redundant beans, if you can just use your constant as is.